# Java Atomic Variable set() vs compareAndSet()

Tags: java, set, atomic, compare-and-swap

I want to know the difference between set() and compareAndSet() in atomic classes. Does the set() method also ensure the atomic process? For example this code:

```
public class sampleAtomic{
    private static AtomicLong id = new AtomicLong(0);

    public void setWithSet(long newValue){
        id.set(newValue);
    }

    public void setWithCompareAndSet(long newValue){
        long oldVal;
        do{
            oldVal = id.get();
        }
        while(!id.compareAndGet(oldVal,newValue)
    }
}
```

Are the two methods identical?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `set` and `compareAndSet` methods act differently:

- compareAndSet :  Atomically sets the value to the given updated value if the current value is equal (==) to the expected value.
- set : Sets to the given value.

> Does the set() method also ensure the atomic process?

Yes. It is atomic. Because there is only one operation involved to `set` the new value. Below is the source code of the `set` method:

```
public final void set(long newValue) {
        value = newValue;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I forgot to check the source code. You are right to say that set method is atomic, but the reason is not because it is only has one operation. Automatic classes has member variable called value and that variable is volatile (the one in the set method body above), so the set method should be thread-safe.

Comment: Are you sure that `Atomic` classes are atomic because they use volatile variables to maintain their internal states. If you define a volatile variable `volatile long value`, does an operation like `value++` is atomic? And the answer is no. This operation is not atomic; it is actually three distinct operations-fetch the value, add one to it, write the updated value back. In the mean time, another thread can change `value`. So having a `volatile` variable doesn't guarantee atomicity.  An operation/process is `atomic`, if they provide support for atomic updates.

Comment: Now, the `set` op is atomic, because it has only one operation: `value = newValue;` and is atomic even if `value` were not defined `volatile`. Here `value` was defined `volatile` to use the visibility guarantee that they provide - changes made by one thread is always visible to the other threads.

Answer (score -1):

As you can see from the open jdk code below.

http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicLong.java#AtomicLong.set%28long%29

`set` is just assigning the value and `compareAndSet` is doing extra operations to ensure atomicity.

http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicLong.java#AtomicLong.compareAndSet%28long%2Clong%29

The return value (boolean) needs to be considered for designing any atomic operations.